# Deploying Node.js app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy an node app to Heroku and I tried using different paths as the starting point of the application in the Procfile configuration without any luck. I was wondering if anyone could help? Please see the details below:

The contents of my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My file structure:

```
> project
  > dist
    > bundle.js
    > index.html
  > src
    > index.js
    > index.html
  package.json
  Procfile
  webpack.config.js
```

The contents of my Procfile are:

```
web: node App.js
```

And finally the error I am getting when I try to deploy to Heroku:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/App.js'
```

If anyone could shed a light on this issue it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is a Node.js application and not a React app? Or do you have something serving the React application?

Comment: Yes you're right it's a React app. I solved the problem by writing this in the Procfile web: node ./src/index.js however I am now having problems with `import React from 'react';` which I guess it's a transpile issue.

Comment: It's all sorted now, I also needed an Express server to serve the static content for this React app. This [guide](http://revelry.media/tech-talk/2016/2/15/getting-a-simple-react-app-on-heroku) explains it really well!

Comment: Glad it got worked out.